# Google Places API does not return the overview you get in UI search

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I am using the Google Places API to search within a radius and then the Place ID to look up a location

The issue I am having is when you search Google through the UI, you get an Overview, basically a short description of what it is. It's not branded Wikipedia or anything so I assumed it's their own content

However I have so far failed to establish how to return this Overview in the API - I can get reviews, and the name, and photos, but not that summary

Am I missing something?

```
     var place_response = await placesClient.GetStringAsync(string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=" + location.place_id + "&fields=name,rating,reviews&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXmE_AMJBCbJP12ADEBU0CU"));
     var place_result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlacesDetailResponse>(place_response);
```

Fields return in place_response do not contain any kind of 'Overview'

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, currently the description/summary of the place is not available via an API. The feature request to expose this value in Places API was filed quite a long time ago. You can see this feature request in Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827225

It looks like Google didn't set high priority on this task. I would suggest starring a feature request in Google issue tracker to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications.